# how to install php with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I'm new to all things related to webservers. Until now, I used apache. But I want to give a try to nginx. So I decided to install it, alongside PHP. This are the steps I followed (I mention that I use Windows 7):

1. download nginx from official website
2. download php5.6.11 from official website
3. I extracted nginx in C:/ drive
4. I extracted and copied php into nginx
5. I created start.bat file (inside nginx folder), with the following code:

   @ECHO OFF
   start C:\nginx\nginx.exe
   start C:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\nginx\php\php.ini-development
   ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NULL
   echo Starting nginx
   echo .
   echo ..
   echo ...
   ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
   EXIT
6. I created stop.bat file (inside nginx folder), with the following code:

   @ECHO OFF
   taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe
   taskkill /f /IM php-cgi.exe
   EXIT
7. I edited nginx/conf/nginx.conf file as follows:

   location ~ .php$ {
       root           html;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
   }
8. I started nginx, with the help of start.bat
9. navigate to 127.0.0.1 in browser, and I got the nginx welcome page.
10. I created a new php file (test.php) into nginx/html/ directory, with a simple code:

But when I navigate to 127.0.0.1/test.php, it takes a long time to respond (a minute), and after that I got the following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred.

Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.
-----------------------------------------------------
```

If I follow the `error log` link, I get this screen:

[image]

Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: this may be better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

After downloading both setups extract them into C:// drive.

put extract php folder in nginx folder.

Now follow steps as I am doing in this video.

To configure PHP in nginx we need to make some changes in nginx.conf file.

Remove old code in nginx.conf file paste below code in nginx.conf.

here is code :

```
location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

To start nginx and php use below batch code:

```
@ECHO OFF
start C:\nginx\nginx.exe
start C:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\nginx\php\php.ini
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NUL
echo Starting nginx
echo .
echo ..
echo ...
ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
EXIT
```

To stop nginx and php use below batch code.

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe
taskkill /f /IM php-cgi.exe
Exit
```